# Andengine texture have strange lines after pressing home and then resuming

Tags: textures, andengine

I have got  very strange error in andengine. My sprites and background are all displayed correctly, but when i minimise the game using Home button, and then resume the texture seems to be corrupted, especially the texture which has shades. Please suggest a possible remedy.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i found the answer , it was related to dithering option.
Query Solved!